# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning: -flat_namespace is deprecated on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I recently updated an old iOS project of mine for the latest version of iOS. I'm running Xcode 8.2.1 and I'm getting the following warning:

`-flat_namespace is deprecated on iOS`

I've looked online but have been unable to figure out what this means. Can anyone explain how to resolve this error?

Comment: @matt Yes, it looks like `flat_namespace` is in the target build settings under "Other Linker Flags". However this isn't listed in the flags specifically so I assume it must be inherited? Not sure exactly what that means though.

Comment: @matt Sorry that's confusing. What I mean is that when I double click on the "Other Linker Flags", there isn't an entry in that list specifically that says `flat_namespace`. However, there is an entry (the first one) that says `$(inherited)` and I believe it is this entry that is pulling in the `flat_namespace` flag. What I'm not sure about is where `$(inherited)` is inheriting from.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, `flat_namespace` was specified in the project build settings, and the target build settings must have been inheriting from that. I removed the `flat_namespace` entry form the project's other linker flags, but now I'm getting a linker error: `ld: can't use -undefined warning or suppress with -twolevel_namespace`

Comment: So if I needed this flag in the past, and it's now deprecated, what do I use instead? The docs you linked don't even mention that `flat_namespace` is deprecated.

Comment: You haven't explained why you needed it. You haven't revealed _anything_ about this project.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure. This project was from several years ago and I don't remember all the details. However, I believe it was related to using Tesseract OCR (https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS) with my project. Not sure if that helps, I can try looking into it more...